# PhoneGap Application reading remote html content

Tags: android, html, cordova

Can I develop hybrid application using phonegap which reads html content at runtime from remote location?

If yes, will it work for both Android as well as iOS?

Comment: here it is shown how to do that . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470380/phonegap-loading-remote-html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is very easy to do on Android and the comment above provides one way to do it. Another is to make AJAX request for the HTML you want and inject it into your page. However Apple will not like this even though it is technically possible. You are better off requesting data via AJAX and then displaying the data in your app rather than pulling down pure HTML.