# JQuery Mobile html + php + phonegap issue

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm learning JQuery mobile (so I apologize if the answer to my question is really obvious).

I modified my simple example of a list of data to use PHP in fetching JSON data and using it to populate my list. My code is as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div data-role='page'>
                <div data-role='header'>
                    testing ... testing 
                </div>
                <?php
                    print "<br>PHP Working!<br>: " + date('d') + "<br>";
                    $json = file_get_contents('http://*.*.*.*/mysite/app/sections');
                    $sections = json_decode($json, true);

                    $sections = $sections['JSON'];
                ?>
                    <ul data-role='listview'>
                <?php
                    foreach ($sections as $key => $section) {
                ?>

                    <li><?php print "<a href='#/{$section['tid']}'>{$section['term']}</a>" ?></li>

                <?php
                    }
                ?>
                        </ul>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

The output in a web browser is in the following image:

[image]

My issue is when I use PhoneGap to generate the Android mobile app, it loads but just prints my PHP code as text.

Can anyone tell me if what I'm trying is possible and if so, what I can do to resolve the issue?

Comment: you need to refresh listview after appending item `$("ul").listview("refresh");`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that you've whitelisted all external urls in your config.xml. So in your case, since you're loading from code.jquery.com, you should have this:

```
<access origin="http://81.16.48.67*" />
<access origin="http://*.jquery.com" />
```

**Edit**

I thought you meant that you had the php on a server and that you were requesting that from the phone with ajax.

The problem is that you can't run php in phonegap, it only supports client-side web technologies (html/css/javascript). So I would recommend using php on a server to generate json data. Then on your phone, fetch that json with ajax and use jquery to put it into the html.

Comment: My project does not have a config.xml. I just have an index.html in my project folder. Can you elaborate?

Comment: When you create phonegap project, you should have a config.xml in the www directory (the same directory as index.html). http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File

Comment: I included a config.xml file but the PhoneGap generated app still just shows raw PHP code

Comment: I would need to see the code on your phone that you're using to load the html from the server.

Comment: I just use a barcode scanner on my old HTC Desire phone to scan the PhoneGap generated barcode and download my app to the phone. I'm not doing anything beyond that. Anything PHP oriented fails. Really confused by this.

Comment: What I meant was, I would need to see the html/javascript in your app, rather than the php on your sever.

Comment: Also, you might want to see this answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11637089/1665818. It would probably be better if your app just requested json with ajax, rather than getting complete html from the server.

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood what you were doing and I've edited my answer.