# Android - PhoneGap 2.0.0 - ChildBrowser - Object #<an Object> has no method 'exec'

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, childbrowser

I am developing an android app using phonegap/cordova 2.0.0.

As of right now, I have a website hosted on my server and my android app is just being used as a wrapper webView.

Here's the code in my java file.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    webview = new WebView(this);

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "jsinterface");

    setContentView(webview);

    // This is where I load the URL of my website
    webview.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.109:3000/");  
}
```

When I deploy the app to an android phone, it works perfectly fine, I am able to see my website in the phone.

The problem I am facing now is to use phonegap plugin especially ChildBrowser (other plugins give me the same result). I have this exception that is being thrown on my javascript console:

```
window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage("http://www.example.com")
TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'exec'
```

I followed the instructions on how to use the plugin [ChildBrowser Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser)

I have included the javascript files on my website hosted on my server

```
<script src="/assets/cordova-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/childbrowser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have spent days trying to figure that out and googled everything I could try. But no luck for me since none of the solutions has worked for me. 
I tried the deviceready option but it didn't work:

> document.addEventListener("deviceready", yourCallbackFunction, false);

Does anybody have a solution for that or is it even possible to call phonegap plugins from an external website?

PS: I have a working example of ChildBrowser but my android app is reading from

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

Comment: are you calling the "window.plugins..." function after deviceReady Event has fired?

Comment: I`m just thinking: Can the page on the web server know what`s inside the android application`s assets folder? I think no but I`m not sure.

Comment: Yes I did try with the deviceready listener. But it is not working for my case. It works well if my app reads from the android application assets folder but when I load the app from my url, it does not work.

Comment: yes that makes sense because the remote server doesnt know Phonegap, it`s inside your android assets folder. So he can´t fire deviceready. Or am I missing out on something?

Comment: You are correct the remote server doesn't know phonegap but I have added cordova.js and childbrowser.js on that remote server hoping that  it will make it work. Do you know if it's possible to use phonegap plugins this way?

Comment: try this, I think it could help you.

[Phonegap: Loading remote HTML][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470380/phonegap-loading-remote-html

Comment: I finally got it to work. Thank you very much. That link you pasted put me on the right track. I also needed to add my url in the config xml and voila !